# How to change the WordPress search results page (using Betheme and Ajax search lite)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, search

I'm currently working on a website for a client and I want to change the search results page. I tried a lot of things but when I search for something on the website I get search results, but without a image or description. My client want the website to show a image and a description.

Here is my search.php code:

```
/**
 * The search template file.
 *
 * @package Betheme
 * @author Muffin group
 * @link https://muffingroup.com
 */
get_header();
$translate['search-title'] = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-search-title','Ooops...') : __('Ooops...','betheme');
$translate['search-subtitle'] = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-search-subtitle','No results found for:') : __('No results found for:','betheme');
$translate['published'] = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-published','Published by') : __('Published by','betheme');
$translate['at'] = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-at','at') : __('at','betheme');
$translate['readmore'] = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-readmore','Read more') : __('Read more','betheme');
?>
<div id="Content">
    <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="sections_group">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="section_wrapper clearfix">
                    <?php if( have_posts() && trim( $_GET['s'] ) ): ?>
                        <div class="column one column_blog">
                            <div class="blog_wrapper isotope_wrapper">
                                <div class="posts_group classic">
                                    <?php
                                        while ( have_posts() ):
                                            the_post();
                                    ?>
                                        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array('post-item', 'clearfix', 'no-img') ); ?>>
                                            <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
                                                <div class="post-desc">
                                                    <?php if( mfn_opts_get( 'blog-meta' ) ): ?>
                                                        <div class="post-meta clearfix">
                                                            <div class="author-date">
                                                                <span class="author"><span><?php echo esc_html($translate['published']); ?> </span><i class="icon-user"></i> <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))); ?>"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></a></span>
                                                                <span class="date"><span><?php echo esc_html($translate['at']); ?> </span><i class="icon-clock"></i> <?php echo esc_html(get_the_date()); ?></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <div class="post-title">
                                                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="post-excerpt">
                                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="post-footer">
                                                        <div class="post-links">
                                                            <i class="icon-doc-text"></i> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-more"><?php echo esc_html($translate['readmore']); ?></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php
                                        endwhile;
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                    if(function_exists( 'mfn_pagination' )):
                                        echo mfn_pagination();
                                    else:
                                        ?>
                                            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_posts_link(esc_html__('&larr; Older Entries', 'betheme')) ?></div>
                                            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_posts_link(esc_html__('Newer Entries &rarr;', 'betheme')) ?></div>
                                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="column one search-not-found">
                            <div class="snf-pic">
                                <i class="themecolor <?php echo esc_attr(mfn_opts_get('error404-icon', 'icon-traffic-cone')); ?>"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="snf-desc">
                                <h2><?php echo esc_html($translate['search-title']); ?></h2>
                                <h4><?php echo esc_html($translate['search-subtitle']) .' '. esc_html($_GET['s']); ?></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if( is_active_sidebar( 'mfn-search' ) ):  ?>
            <div class="sidebar four columns">
                <div class="widget-area clearfix <?php echo esc_attr(mfn_opts_get('sidebar-lines')); ?>">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'mfn-search' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Which parts of you rcode are problematic?

Comment: I want to show a tumbnail and a discription in the search results page, now i only see the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');  ?>
<div class="post-img">
<img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>"/>
</div>
```

use above code in while loop to show image by using post id.